# Data Ingestion Into HDFS by unique technique

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I want to transfer Un-semi structured data(MS word/PDF/JSON) from a remote computer into hadoop(could be in batch and could be near realtime but not stream).

I have to Make sure that data is moved quickly from Remote location to my local machine(working on low bandwidth)into HDFS or local machine. 
Fro example Internet Download Manager has this amazing technique of making several connections with the FTP and utilizing low bandwidth with more connections.

Is there any possibility that Hadoop ecosystem provides such a tool to ingest data into hadoop. Or any self made technique?

Which Tool/Technique could be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Web HDFS API http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Document_Conventions